# Dynamically casting an Entity Model from SQL query results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I need to dynamically cast a SQL return value to a model like this

```
var data = _db.Query<myModel>(myStoredProcedure, p, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

The above works as it should as the model is explicit in the casting.

However, myModel could be any type of model class that I have in my project. I am able to get the actual model through reflection and the use of a string variable called "TableName" 
I thought I could go this routine to set it but I get the error of 'entityObject is a variable but used like a type'

```
 //First we need to find the project that holds all of our entity models in the assembly
                    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("MyProject.Models")).FirstOrDefault();

                    //Now we need to search through the assembly to match the Entity to the supplied TableName
                    var type = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == localTableName);

                    //Once found then we create a dynamic instance of the entity using reflection
                    if (type != null)
                    {
                        var ctx = new MyProject.Models.Entities();

                       //Create the DBSet here
                        System.Data.Entity.DbSet myDbSet = ctx.Set(type);

                        //Now create the actual entity reference which is just an object at this point
                        var entityObject = myDbSet.Create();


--> Errors here var data = _db.Query<entityObject>(myStoredProcedure, p, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Should I use ExpandoObject? If so how can convert the expandoobject into the entityClass?

Comment: Are you saying you won't know what Type a stored procedure will return? You should be able to write a generic method and not use reflection at all

Comment: Yes it will return a list of results that will go 1:1 with an entity. I need to cast those results to its correct entity model. It could be any of 30 models

Comment: how about this `ctx.Database.SqlQuery(type, String.Format("exec {0}", myStoredProcedure)).ToList();`

Comment: @RajN that doesnt work.